# Com interface with fixed size array

Tags: nav

I need to expose a COM interface with a method that implement one fixed size array parameter.
The array size is fixed because the consumer is based on a tecnology in which you must declare the array size.
So I could do something like this

```
[Guid("2AE7C342-89ED-492B-B9AA-92A778332000")]
public interface _DocSolutionsClassic

{
    [DispId(1)]
    void Execute( string[] InputParams);
}
```

and it works for me, but there is a different dimension error by the consumer.

I would like to write something lik this

```
[DispId(1)]
void Execute( string[50] InputParams);
```

or this

```
[DispId(1)]
string[] InputParams = new string[50];
void Execute(string[] InputParams);
```

But Vstudio 2010 give me an error...

Comment: The 'string' is not really a type that should be used as a parameter in COM method. You should go with BSTR, or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this could help:

IDL code snippet:

```
[id(1), helpstring("method foobar")] HRESULT foobar( BSTR * bstrs, ULONG size );
```

This way you can send any number of strings. The 'size' parameter is actually the number of strings that 'bstrs' points to.

Note:
Use `SysAllocString()`/`SysFreeString()` for string allocation/deallocation (or some equivalent in your environment).